# Where is apt-front on 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am looking for apt-front on Ubuntu 16.04 because I get the error `fatal error: apt-front/utils/shared.h: No such file or directory`. On Ubuntu 14.04 I see:

```
# aptitude search apt-front
i   libapt-front-dev              - High-level library for managing Debian packages
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 I don't get it:

```
# aptitude search  libapt-front
#
```

My source list is:

```
# grep ^deb sources.list
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Am I missing an url? What can I do on Ubuntu 16.04?

`apt-cache policy libapt-front-dev` shows this:

```
# apt-cache policy libapt-front-dev
libapt-front-dev:
  Installiert:           0.4.0-0.2ubuntu1
  Installationskandidat: 0.4.0-0.2ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.4.0-0.2ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on AU

Comment: What do you mean by AU?

Comment: Ask Ubuntu: this should be migrated there...

Comment: There is nobody answering. Therefore I tried it here.

Comment: Don't [crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt I updated the question. It is not from a package because the Ubuntu source is missing isn't it?

Comment: It is a package, it's just no longer available in Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll try [this](https://quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net/~slavek-banko/+archive/ubuntu/deps-r14/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) for 16.04. Maybe it works. Do you know this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your question — but no, I don't know those packages.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, the problem is reproducible, and is relevant for any Debian derivative, not just Ubuntu. So I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @StephenKitt As for my close-vote, probably because of the ambiguous "*Here is the answer of the question*"-edit which sounded like OP solved his own problem.

Comment: @techraf I wondered if that had contributed! It did indeed sound like the OP had solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libapt-front` was [removed from Debian in 2009](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=513111), and as a result from Ubuntu too (perhaps a little later). I'm surprised you have it in 14.04; Launchpad [doesn't list it in any supported version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapt-front) (including 14.04 which is still supported). Presumably it was installed from some other source, or left over from an older version; in any case, using it is probably not a good idea.

It was apparently last included in Ubuntu in Jaunty; you can find the source code for that version of the package in [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapt-front).

Comment: I found the sources and the deb on 14.04. I made the deb work on 16.04 but the sources are hopeless. Thanks a lot!